# Presto MySQL Connector: 'DROP TABLE is disabled in this catalog'

Tags: mysql-connector, presto

According to Presto MySQL connector [docs](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/mysql.html) I see that DROP table is supported operation for this connector.

Yet I receive `DROP TABLE is disabled in this catalog` when I try to do `DROP table` operation.

Is this some setting in the catalog .properties file?

Answer (score 4):

I found that there is a property in .properties file of the catalog.

```
allow-drop-table=true
```

It does the job.